# sort array of objects by number of object fields matched

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, object

I have the following object:

```
var entries = [
  {
    fields: {
      tags: [
        { fields: { id: "football" } },
        { fields: { id: "running" } },
        { fields: { id: "tennis" } }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    fields: {
      tags: [
        { fields: { id: "tennis" } },
        { fields: { id: "football" } },
        { fields: { id: "rugby" } }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    fields: {
      tags: [
        { fields: { id: "cricket" } },
        { fields: { id: "running" } }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    fields: {
      tags: [
        { fields: { id: "football" } },
        { fields: { id: "rugby" } }
      ]
    }
  }
];
```

Now, I want to sort the array using another array: `var testArray = ["football", "rugby"]`

So any of the objects that contain both `rugby` and `football` in their `fields.tags.fields.id` should return first in the array, then any that just contain 1 should appear next. So the results I'm after would be:

```
var sortedEntries = [
  {
    fields: {
      tags: [
        { fields: { id: "tennis" } },
        { fields: { id: "football" } },
        { fields: { id: "rugby" } }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    fields: {
      tags: [
        { fields: { id: "football" } },
        { fields: { id: "rugby" } }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    fields: {
      tags: [
        { fields: { id: "football" } },
        { fields: { id: "running" } },
        { fields: { id: "tennis" } }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    fields: {
      tags: [
        { fields: { id: "cricket" } },
        { fields: { id: "running" } }
      ]
    }
  }
];
```

I thought this might be possible using the `sort()` function but then I realised I need to compare my `testArray` to see how many items are matched. Is this possible? I can't find any examples online of what I'm trying to do and I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Gah, I answered this the last time you asked it but you deleted it before I had a chance to complete the write-up!

Comment: Don't worry, I recoded it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution optimized for large datasets, with temporary storage of count.

```js
var search = ['football', 'rugby'],
    entries = [{ fields: { tags: [{ fields: { id: "cricket" } }, { fields: { id: "running" } }] } }, { fields: { tags: [{ fields: { id: "football" } }, { fields: { id: "running" } }, { fields: { id: "tennis" } }] } }, { fields: { tags: [{ fields: { id: "tennis" } }, { fields: { id: "football" } }, { fields: { id: "rugby" } }] } }, { fields: { tags: [{ fields: { id: "football" } }, { fields: { id: "rugby" } }] } }],
    sortedData = entries.map(function (a) {
        a.count = a.fields.tags.reduce(function (r, b) { return r + !!~search.indexOf(b.fields.id); }, 0);
        return a;
    }, []).sort(function (a, b) { return b.count - a.count; }).map(function (a) {
        delete a.count;
        return a;
    }, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sortedData, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Solution optimized for small datasets, without temporary storage of count.

```js
var search = ['football', 'rugby'],
    entries = [{ fields: { tags: [{ fields: { id: "cricket" } }, { fields: { id: "running" } }] } }, { fields: { tags: [{ fields: { id: "football" } }, { fields: { id: "running" } }, { fields: { id: "tennis" } }] } }, { fields: { tags: [{ fields: { id: "tennis" } }, { fields: { id: "football" } }, { fields: { id: "rugby" } }] } }, { fields: { tags: [{ fields: { id: "football" } }, { fields: { id: "rugby" } }] } }],
    sortedData = entries.sort(function (a, b) {
        function f(r, c) { return r + !!~search.indexOf(c.fields.id); }
        return b.fields.tags.reduce(f, 0) - a.fields.tags.reduce(f, 0);
    });
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sortedData, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Interesting, this seems to work well. My only worry is that it's not very readable (this level of javascript is a bit beyond me). Would this not be suitable for smaller datasets?

Comment: it works for any size, but for smaller sets, there is a shorter version possible.

Comment: I guess it depends on where the line is drawn between large and small then. The data I'm dealing with will have those objects bloated will all sorts of other stuff, and there may be up to 30 or 40 main objects in the entries array.

Comment: 30 or 40 is small, just try it with real data sets.

Comment: I think this has to steal the accepted answer. Short and sweet with 2 good and working options there.

Answer (score 1):

Custom sort function that filters the tags arrays and checks lengths of those matches

```
entries.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aMatches = a.fields.tags.filter(function (item) {
        return testArray.indexOf(item.fields.id) > -1
    });
    var bMatches = b.fields.tags.filter(function (item) {
        return testArray.indexOf(item.fields.id) > -1
    });
    return bMatches.length - aMatches.length;
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pykwpx1s/)**</kbd>

Comment: @Coop looks like some of the others are filtering out non matches and I didn't. Not sure what expectations are for those

Comment: I think it could get a bit problematic that you recount matches on every comparsion.

Comment: @Yoshi point taken, would defintiely bog down on large data sets

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with a custom sort function that would check how many items in `tags` exist in `testArray`. Something like this should work:

```
var testArray = ["football", "rugby"];
entries.sort(function(a, b) {
    var a_score = 0;
    var b_score = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<a.fields.tags.length; i++) {
        if (testArray.indexOf(a.fields.tags[i]) > -1) {
            a_score++;
        }
    }
    for (var i=0; i<b.fields.tags.length; i++) {
        if (testArray.indexOf(b.fields.tags[i]) > -1) {
            b_score++;
        }
    }
    return b_score-a_score;
});
```

Comment: You need to return those objects that contain the search terms as well as sorting it.